# ¿Como agregar otra propiedad al objeto que me retorna una consutla en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hola a todos de ante mano muchas gracias por sus respuestas y comnetarios la pregunta es la siguiente quiero agregar otra clave y valor al objeto que me retorna una consulta, tengo la siguiente consulta uitlizando Query Builder de Laravel.

```
$query = DB::table($table)->get()->toArray();
```

Esta consulta me retorna el siguiente objeto:

```
   1: {id: 1, genero: "femenino", visible: "femenino"}
   2: {id: 2, genero: "masculino", visible: "masculino"}
```

Ahora quiero agregar al objeto que me hes retornado una nuva clave y valor qudando de la siguiente manera:

```
   1: {id: 1, genero: "femenino", visible: "femenino", table: 'genero' }
   2: {id: 2, genero: "masculino", visible: "masculino", table: 'genero' }
```

El nombre de la tabla que quiero agregar lo tengo almacenado en una variable $table de la siguiente forma:

```
$table = 'genero';
$query = DB::table($table)->get()->toArray();
```

¿Como puedo agregar el nombre de la tabla de la que provienen los registros?

Les agradezco sus respuestas y comentarios por cierto no puedo utillizar eloquent para generar la consuta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacer un foreach para añadir a cada uno de los objetos del array

```
$data = DB::table($table)->get()->toArray();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $value->table = $table;
}
return $data;
```

donde `$value->table` es la key, y `$table` es el valor que agregas.

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo normalmente haria cuando necesito el mismo valor estatico en cada fila de una consulta es lo siguiente:

```
$table = "genero";
$query = DB::table($table)->select('*', DB::raw("'".$table."' as table"))->get()->toArray();
```

No se realmente cual respuesta es mas eficiente.